# Framework (API) for BlueTooth LE 4.0 (C# .NET)

Tags: c#, bluetooth-lowenergy

For a new C# WinForms project I need an information about the frameworks or APIs supported BlueTooth LowEnergy 4.0

The second question is about the system requirements: so I have already found 32feet.net and it seems to require Windows 8 - but what is about **Windows XP (SP2) / Vista / Windows 7**? **Have this systems any support for BLE 4.0 ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://xamarin.com/ provides the abstraction for Bluetooth Low Energy in C#.
Probably you can explore this.

Comment: but are those C# wrappers for iOS and OS X? but not for Windows 7 or 8.